CGAL Linker Error CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-gd-4.13.1.lib can not open
I have to do a Project with CGAl. If I run a Project for example Hello World with Visual Studio 17 i get this Linker Error CGAL Core vc140 mt gd 4.13.1 lib file can not open.
I use a Windows 10 with visual studio 17.
For CGAl an the Boost I use CGAL 4.11 Setup and the boost I use boost 1 65 1 msvc 14.1.
Moreover I use the version 3.31.0 for cmake.
This is my Project
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Segment_2 Segment_2;

int main()
{
    Point_2 p(1, 1), q(10, 10);

    std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << "q = " << q.x() << " " << q.y() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "sqdist(p,q) = "
        << CGAL::squared_distance(p, q) << std::endl;

    Segment_2 s(p, q);
    Point_2 m(5, 9);

    std::cout << "m = " << m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sqdist(Segment_2(p,q), m) = "
        << CGAL::squared_distance(s, m) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "p, q, and m ";
    switch (CGAL::orientation(p, q, m)) {
    case CGAL::COLLINEAR:
        std::cout << "are collinear\n";
        break;
    case CGAL::LEFT_TURN:
        std::cout << "make a left turn\n";
        break;
    case CGAL::RIGHT_TURN:
        std::cout << "make a right turn\n";
        break;
    }

    std::cout << " midpoint(p,q) = " << CGAL::midpoint(p, q) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

If I run this I get This Linker Error
LNK1104 file "CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-gd-4.13.1.lib" can not open.   Hello_world_CGAL    
C:\Users\Besitzer\source\repos\Hello_world_CGAL\Hello_world_CGAL\LINK   1   


In the Properties for the compieler i Add this
C:\local\CGAL-4.11\auxiliary\gmp\include
C:\local\boost_1_65_1
C:\local\boost_1_65_1\build\include
C:\local\CGAL-4.11\include

For the Properties for the linker I used these directories
C:\local\CGAL-4.11\auxiliary\gmp\libs
C:\local\boost_1_65_1\libs
C:\local\boost_1_65_1\lib64-msvc-14.1
C:\local\CGAL-4.11\build\lib

I checked whether this lib file exists and I found this file. Also i check in the interet wiht simular Question but I found not much.

I Found a solution to this Project I Add the wrong .lib to this Project after i corecct the lib it's Working.

Another solution might be to upgrade CGAL.  It is header only now.
